# making parallel calls in C# - How to Identify which call failed

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to Parallel call in .Net core, please help me.

I am making Parallel call, so I would like to know here if any calls fails in If one of out of many calls fails or all calls failed then we should write to logs specific which Permanent ID got failed. Please help me how to Identify which one failed

```
foreach (var permanentId in permanentIds)
        { 
            Request1 request = new Request1 ()
            {
                AccountID =  permanentId // "02134665300468820" 
             };

                tasks.Add(ModelServiceProcessing(request).ContinueWith(
                        (TResult) => ServiceList.Add(TResult.Result)));

         }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: Check the individual `Task` objects after failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the individual tasks upon failure:

```
try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
catch
{
    List<Task> failedTasks = tasks.Where(t => t.IsFaulted).ToList();
    // do something with failed tasks
    throw;
}
```

[`IsFaulted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_IsFaulted) will return `true` if the `Task` failed due to an unhandled exception.

If you need to map tasks to request objects, you should save a mapping between the Task and the AccountID when you create the task. Although `Task.Id` exists, it's not guaranteed to be unique so I'd be wary of using it. For example:

```
Dictionary<Task, string> taskAccountMap = new Dictionary<Task, string>();

foreach (var permanentId in permanentIds)
{
    Request1 request = new Request1 ()
    {
        AccountID =  permanentId // "02134665300468820" 
    };

    Task requestTask = ModelServiceProcessing(request).ContinueWith(
                    (TResult) => ServiceList.Add(TResult.Result));
    taskAccountMap[requestTask] = permanentId;
    tasks.Add(requestTask);
}
```

And when in your catch, you can get the id like so:

```
catch
{
    List<Task> failedTasks = tasks.Where(t => t.IsFaulted).ToList();
    foreach (Task t in failedTasks)
    {
        string permanentId = taskAccountMap[t];
        // do something with the id
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi John, when I am trying to implement your logic , I am getting an error message in the below line - Cannot Implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'   here is the line Task requestTask = ModelServiceProcessing(request).ContinueWith(
                    (TResult) => ServiceList.Add(TResult.Result));

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour. Every overload of `ContinueWith` returns a `Task` or `Task<T>`, so I don't see how you're getting `void`. Certainly your prior use of `tasks.Add(SAMECODE);` would not have worked if that method wasn't returning `Task`, and you can't create a `List<void>`, so it must be `List<Task> tasks`, right?

Comment: one last question, I am almost near - in the Catch block -> tasks.Where - here I am getting an error message.
'List<Task>' does not contain defination for where and no accessible extension method 'where' accepting a first argument of type
'List<Task>' could be found

Comment: You need to include `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code. In .NET Framework projects, Visual Studio would add this by default, but in .NET Core projects you need to add it manually if you need it. You can often click on such code with that kind of message and press `Ctrl`+`.` on the keyboard. It should prompt you to add the appropriate `using`.